# UML diagrams: if ClassA accesses ClassC through ClassB, is there a dependency from ClassA to ClassC?

Tags: java, oop, uml

For example, if classA calls classB.getClassC().foo(), there is a dependency between ClassA and ClassB, but is there also a dependency between ClassA and ClassC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> classA calls classB.getClassC().foo()

both calls are done in an operation of the class A, the fact the instance of C is get from an operation of B changes nothing about that, so the class A uses the classes C and you can indicate that with a dependencies from A to C (if there is no 'stronger' relation for an other reason).

Between the class A and the class B you do not give enough detail to know if there is an association or just a dependency. Is *getClassC* a static operation of the class B ? Else if *classB* correspond to an instance of B you do not say if it is an attribute of the class A or received through a parameter of the operation doing the code you give etc

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I wasn't clear on ClassB, I just wasn't concerned about it. You can assume getClassC() is static.

Comment: @yournamehere in that case and without other reasons a dependency ` A - - - <<use>>- - -> B` is enough (to enter in detail *use* is a keyword, not a stereotype, even that changes nothing in a class diagram)